# Get-WmiObject - show only lines - Description, Service and SystemName - powershell

Tags: powershell, filter, output, get-wmiobject

I have this piece of script in powershell to list USB devices on computer:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_USBControllerDevice | Foreach-Object { [Wmi]$_.Dependent }
```

This is a part of output:

```
__GENUS                     : 2
__CLASS                     : Win32_PnPEntity
__SUPERCLASS                : CIM_LogicalDevice
__DYNASTY                   : CIM_ManagedSystemElement
__RELPATH                   : Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USB\\VID_0424&PID_5534\\5&38E06FA4&0&14"
__PROPERTY_COUNT            : 24
__DERIVATION                : {CIM_LogicalDevice, CIM_LogicalElement, CIM_ManagedSystemElement}
__SERVER                    : OTLB674G
__NAMESPACE                 : root\cimv2
__PATH                      : \\OTLB674G\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USB\\VID_0424&PID_5534\\5&38E06FA4&0&14" 
Availability                :  
Caption                     : Rozbočovač USB 3.0 
ClassGuid                   : {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000} 
CompatibleID                : {IUSB3\Class_09&SubClass_00&Prot_03, IUSB3\Class_09&SubClass_00, IUSB3\Class_09} 
ConfigManagerErrorCode      : 0 
ConfigManagerUserConfig     : False 
CreationClassName           : Win32_PnPEntity 
Description                 : Rozbočovač USB 3.0 
DeviceID                    : USB\VID_0424&PID_5534\5&38E06FA4&0&14 
ErrorCleared                :  
ErrorDescription            :  
HardwareID                  : {USB\VID_0424&PID_5534&REV_6082} 
InstallDate                 :  
LastErrorCode               :  
Manufacturer                : Intel(R) Corporation 
Name                        : Rozbočovač USB 3.0 
PNPDeviceID                 : USB\VID_0424&PID_5534\5&38E06FA4&0&14 PowerManagementCapabilities     :  
PowerManagementSupported    :  
Service                     : iusb3hub 
Status                      : OK 
StatusInfo                  :  
SystemCreationClassName     : Win32_ComputerSystem 
SystemName                  : OTLB674G 
PSComputerName              : OTLB674G
```

I know how to show filter only running services for Get-service, but I can't figure it out how to filter only lines - Description, Service and SystemName to be shown in output.

I will be gratefull for any help.

Thanks in advance,
Joseph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pipe the output to the [Select-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113387) cmdlet and specify the properties you want to select:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_USBControllerDevice | Foreach-Object {
    [Wmi]$_.Dependent | Select-Object Description, Service, SystemName
}
```